# Can we detect atmosphere on exoplanets?

Tags: atmosphere, exoplanet

We are [finding new planets](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3823) in other solar systems all the time.  Some of them are in a [habitable zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone) of their sun.  Are we able to detect the atmosphere of any exoplanet?  Is there any atmospheric element that would be indicative of known life forms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are starting to examine exoplanet atmospheres. A spectroscopic analysis is made of the light from a exoplanet transiting its star. The spectra of the star is subtracted from the combined star/planet data, and the remainder is assumed to be the absorption spectra from light passing through the planet's atmosphere. Here's an article from a recent Centauri Dreams column that goes into some detail: [Tau Boötis b: A ’3-D’ Look at Star and Planet.](http://www.centauri-dreams.org/?p=30039)

As far as elements indicative of life forms, one would expect to see water, carbon dioxide and methane on a life-bearing planet, but, of course, these are common substances that can readily be explained by natural processes.

Comment: That works for planets detected by the transit method, but do you know of any techniques for planets detected by other methods such as star wobble (radial velocity)?